# Hyperlinks doesn't open in MarkdownTextBlock control in windows universal application

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, markdown, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I have below code in my view (XAML)

```
<Page
x:Class="MyProject1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Black">
<Grid Background="White" Name="mainGrid">

    <Border  BorderBrush="Cyan" BorderThickness="0.2" Margin="3,0,3,3">
        <ListView x:Name="ListView" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:MarkdownTextBlock Name="markdownBlock" Text="[link](www.google.com)">
                    </controls:MarkdownTextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

I am trying to render hyperlinks in `MarkdownTextBlock` control, however when I click on hyperlink, there is no effect.

Same code when I run in browser, works fine.. I mean, I can click on the link and then the new tab/browser opens up for the http request.

What am i missing in my `MarkdownTextBlock` control in above xaml code?
Do I need to add any property for the link click to be enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the link cliecked event manually where you can launch the browser to the clicked link.

**View.xaml**

```
<controls:MarkdownTextBlock Name="markdownBlock" Text="[link](www.google.com)" LinkClicked="MarkdownText_LinkClicked">
```

**View.xaml.cs**

```
private async void MarkdownText_LinkClicked(object sender, UI.Controls.LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(e.Link));
}
```